# Unit conversion from user's file entered in command prompt

Tags: c, arrays

In my C programming class we are supposed to write a program that is able to perform unit conversion. This is to be done by taking a filename and the desired conversion from the user, opening the file, identifying the conversion factors within the file, closing the file, and displaying the final conversion.

Here is the sample file **lengths** that the instructor provided:

```
INCH 0.0254
FOOT 0.3048
YARD 0.9144
MILE 1609.344
MM 1e-3
CM 1e-2
METER 1
KM 1e3
AU 149597870700.0
```

Here is sample output that we need to replicate exactly:

```
% c11 -Wall units.c -o u
% ./u lengths 12 inch foot
12.00 inch is 1.00 foot.
% ./u lengths 30 inch foot
30.00 inch is 2.50 foot.
% ./u lengths 1 foot inch
1.00 foot is 12.00 inch.
% ./u lengths 1 inch foot
1.00 inch is 0.08 foot.
% ./u lengths 1 au mile
1.00 au is 92955807.27 mile.
% ./u lengths 1000 meter km
1000.00 meter is 1.00 km.
% ./u lengths 1 inch mile
1.00 inch is 0.00 mile.
% ./u
usage: ./u <unitfile> <amount> <from> <to>
% ./u lengthz 1 inch foot
./u: can’t open file lengthz
% ./u lengths 1 inch feet
./u: no such unit "feet"
```

What libraries must I include in order to make this program work? What is the best way to take input from the user in this situation?

**Update:**
After a bit of trial and error, I was able to get my program to take the command line arguments. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Function to take file name from the user input
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 5)
    {
            printf("usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
            FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (file == 0)
            {
                    printf("can't open file %s\n", argv[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                    int x;
                    while ((x = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
                    {
                            printf("%c", x);
                    }
                    fclose(file);
            }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this only prints the contents of the file assuming that the program gets 5 command line arguments.

Comment: "What is the best way to take input from the user in this situation?" -- This question is unclear; it looks like you are not taking interactive input from the user, but instead getting input from the command-line. In any case, you should probably make an attempt and provide code with a specific question when you encounter problems.

Comment: My mistake, I assumed that taking input was considered user input regardless of that input being obtained via the command line or via a prompt after the program is already running.

Comment: looks like all your input comes from the command line. You won't need any special libraries, all the math should be multiplication and division. First things first, read and verify the command line arguments.

Comment: Fine to consider it user input, but "what is the best way" is unclear. What do you mean by this? There is really only one way to take input from the command-line in C.

Comment: @yano -- library functions may be needed to convert string values to numeric values....

Comment: @DavidBowling Sure,, I just mean, in all of my build environments at least, I've never had to explicitly link in other libraries for that functionality. I've used [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) plenty (haven't used [`strtod`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) but it looks similar). The math library, for instance, shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: If there is only one way to take input from the command-line in C, then I suppose I am looking for a syntactical example of exactly how I would do that, relevant to the assignment that I am working on. I have been unable to find information that I understand thus far relevant to the assignment.

Comment: @AustinButterfield do `argc` and `argv` sound familiar?

Comment: @yano Yes we have talked about them briefly during class.

Comment: That's what you use to access command line arguments. `argc` is the number of arguments, `argv` is a list of the arguments. A Google or SO search "c reading command line arguments" will turn up many examples of how to use these.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try and come back with some code hopefully.

Comment: @yano I was able to pass the arguments via the command line. Any recommendation on what to do next?

Comment: I'd recommend using `fgets` to read the file in one line at a time. Each line has the format "unit <space> conversionFactor", so you can parse each line on that space. Use `strtod` I linked earlier to convert from string to `double` (or the `float` version if that's enough precision). Have you done any of this before? Command line arguments? Read from file? Parse strings? These are a lot of concepts to throw all together new in one assignment.

Comment: @yano I have very little experience in C, which is the reason I'm struggling so heavily with this assignment. Should reading the file take place instead of the `printf` command in the `while` statement?

Comment: Youre already reading the file, `fgetc` reads one character at a time from the file. `fgets` will read one _line_ at a time. I'm sorry, but SO isn't a tutoring site, and even it is was the comment section isn't the place to learn how to do all these things. You're just going to have to take some time and research it.  This is how I would break it down into smaller problems to google/solve. 1) read (and verify) command line arguments. You're reading them kind of, not yet verifying 2) Parse a string. In this case, find the space on each line and use that to separate the unit from the

Comment: @yano Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: conversion factor. 3) Covert a string to a float/double. The function I linked will do this. 4) associate each unit with it's conversion factor. I would use an array of `struct{ char* unitName; double convFactor; }` to do this. And finally 5) Use the rest of the arguments to select the appropriate conversion factors (from your struct array if you did that) and perform the math, print out the result. Good luck! If you've got a specific question moving forward, ask a new one.